# Using the .map function to create an array of image alt text inside a specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, function

I have a page I'm using to grab image alt text from a slider. Each image has a different alt text, and I'm trying to pull it into an array and then loop through it to display it.

However when I implement it, it only adds one object to the array as opposed to how ever many it may ACTUALLY have inside the div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tn_array = $("#rightSlider img").map(function () {
        return $(this).attr("alt");
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < tn_array.length; i++) {
        alert(tn_array[i]);
        $('#links').append('<a href="#" title="' + tn_array[i] + '" >' + tn_array[i] + '</a><br />');
    }
});
```

Here is the main page that the code grabs the alt text from:

```
<div id="rightSlider">
    <div>
        <img src="images/adptvtch_s1_1.jpg" alt="Hearing Aid On A Female's Ear" width="330" height="215" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/adptvtch_s1_2.jpg" alt="Hands Reading Braille Book" width="330" height="215" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/adptvtch_s1_3.jpg" alt="Man In Wheelchair Reading" width="330" height="215" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried other things such as .each and I can't seem to pinpoint why it's only adding the first alt text and not the other ones. If you guys can help me figure it out, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Comment: var tn_array = [];
$("#rightSlider img").each(function() { tn_array.push($(this).attr('alt')); });

Comment: Seems to be working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/923kg/

Comment: `var arr = $.map($("#rightSlider img"), function(el) {return el.getAttribute('alt'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need additional `iteration` and an unnecessary `array` manipulation.

Try this,

```
 var xEle = $('#links');

 $("#rightSlider img").each(function() {
   xEle.append('<a href="#" title="'+ $(this).attr("alt") +'" >'+ $(this).attr("alt") +'</a><br />');
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/923kg/1/)

Comment: I think my issue is to do with other functions running on my page. As I've tested and it does in fact work on other pages except this one. I'm going to give you the answer, as I'm a fan of cleaner code and less redundancies. But at least I know where the issue is.